# Editable ComboBox in Microsoft Access

Tags: vba, vbscript, ms-access-2007, ms-office, office-2010

I am try to add something close to an editable combo box to my Access form where users can either type what they need or choose from a list of available entries. I am new to access and would appreciate any information on how this can be done.

Nothing happens when I test the code below.

Code

```
Private Sub ddlUNS1_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)
    Dim ctl As Control

    ' Return Control object that points to combo box.
    Set ctl = Me!ddlUNSC1

    If MsgBox("Value is not in list. Add it?", vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then

        MsgBox ("ddlUNSLEVEL NOT LISTED FIRED ")
    Else 
        'ctl.Undo
        MsgBox ("ddlUNSLEVEL  LISTED FIRED ")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Editable, Appendable ComboBox(?) in MS Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019039/editable-appendable-combobox-in-ms-access)

Answer (score 0):

There are various options. You can refer back to the bound field:

```
Row Source: SELECT DISTINCT AddressType FROM ThisTable
Control Source : AddressType
```

This is of limited use, and probably only useful for a short-term database.

You can use [NotInList and LimitToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb214329%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to add new values.

Comment: That seems to be what I need. I will try it and update this thread

Comment: I set this but does not seem to be giving me the solution I require. Is there something I could possibly be missing?

Comment: Please edit your question to include your current code and a note on what is not happening that you want to see happening.

Comment: I have added the change. Essentially, nothing happens when I hope this and try to test it by making changes.

Comment: Did you set Limit To List to Yes?